# Mongodb: batch jobs and deleting data

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a batch job to aggregate some data using the aggregation framework. Since the data output is potentially large, I am using a `$limit` in the top of my pipeline to reduce the number of objects that are processed at a time. My question is: after the aggregation is complete, how would I reliably remove all the objects that have been processed from the collection without having to worry about race conditions? Or if there's another way to go about what I am trying to do?

Comment: what race conditions are you worried about?

Comment: Let's say run an aggregation on the first 1000 records of collection A, and save the result to collection B. Then I want to remove those 1000 records in collection A which I have just processed. But, there's a possibility that at this point, another process has inserted more records in front of those 1000.

Comment: "in front of" - I would assume that you would chunk your data on a deterministic boundry (date, id value, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
1> rename your collection

2> Now do all your processing on the new collection.
```

*Warning: It doesn't work well in Sharded environments*